# How do I draw on a Qlabel with QPainter when multithreading with QThreadpool?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Please excuse me if my description isn't perfect, I'm still pretty new at PyQt and also Python in general. If you have recommendations on how to improve the question, please let me know.

I'm trying to draw on a Pixmap-QLabel, which is part of a QMainWindow, with QPainter. The QPainter is called in a loop, because the drawing is updated after a fixed duration. Drawing on the Pixmap works as intended, the problem I have is that the label always opens in a new window, instead of being placed on the QLabel inside the original QMainWindow.

I suspect that the reason for that is that I'm calling the QPainter from a Worker-class-object which is created by the QThreadpool-object. If I call the QPainter from inside the initialization of the GUI, the Pixmap-label is created as part of the QMainWindow as intended. Unfortunately the multithreading is necessary so the GUI stays responsive while the QLabel is updating.

The GUI itself is created with QtCreator, and simply loaded into the script.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QPaintEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        self.counter = 0

        # load ui which can be designed with Qt Creator
        uic.loadUi("ui/paintEvent_Loop.ui", self)

        # find the QLabel where the picture should be placed
        self.pixmap_label = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLabel, "pixmap_label")

        # creating the pixmap-label here works as intended
        '''self.draw_label = PixmapLabel(self.pixmap_label)
        self.draw_label.setGeometry(130, 50, 911, 512)
        self.draw_label.show()'''

        self.label = self.findChild(QLabel, "label")

        # find the button with the name "cancel_button"
        self.cancel_button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, "cancel_button")
        self.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.close_application)

        # find the start_button button
        self.start_button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, "start_button")
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_loop)

        self.pause_cont_button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pause_cont_button")
        self.pause_cont_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle_pause_continue)
        self.pause_cont_button.hide()

        # create the QThreadPool object to manage multiple threads
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.run_loop = True

        # show application
        self.show()

    def close_application(self):
        app.quit()

    def toggle_pause_continue(self):
        """
        changes the value of boolean run_loop to pause and continue the loop through the samples in the chosen scene
        :return:
        """
        if self.run_loop:
            self.run_loop = False
        else:
            self.run_loop = True

    def start_loop(self):
        # hide start_button and show pause_cont_button
        self.start_button.hide()
        self.pause_cont_button.show()
        self.pause_cont_button.setCheckable(True)

        # start one further thread managed by threadpool
        worker = Worker()
        self.threadpool.start(worker)


class PixmapLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PixmapLabel, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def paintEvent(self, a0: QPaintEvent) -> None:

        # initiate QPainter instance
        painter = QPainter(window.draw_label)

        # open image
        picture = QPixmap(os.getcwd() + '/test-image.png')
        myPicturePixmap = picture.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setPixmap(myPicturePixmap)

        # draw red box on it
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), myPicturePixmap)
        pen = QPen(Qt.red, 3)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    # worker thread
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        print("Thread start")

        for self.i in range(0, 50):

            # create pixmap_label with drawings
            # FIXME: make pixmap-label part of original GUI
            window.draw_label = PixmapLabel(window.pixmap_label)
            window.draw_label.setGeometry(130, 50, 911, 512)
            window.draw_label.show()

            window.label.setText(str(self.i))

            while window.run_loop == False:
                time.sleep(0.05)

            # show image for 0.5 seconds, then update image
            time.sleep(0.5)
            window.draw_label.destroy()
            time.sleep(0.05)



        # print in terminal to know that we are finished
        print("Thread complete")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    app.exec_()
```

The image I'm using:

[image: test-image.png]

Comment: Qt does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread. But in any case, I don't see any evidence that your example would benefit much from multi-threading. If the images are large, it might help to pre-load and cache batches of them in the background. But that would have to be done using `QImage` rather than `QPixmap`, and the actual rendering of the pixmaps must all be done in the main thread. But before you bother with any of that, you should create a non-multi-threaded example which just loads the images via a timer. That will probably work fine if the images aren't huge.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks a lot, I'll try that

Comment: 2 Things @WishICouldCode that you should be aware of -- first QThreadPool is a very specific usage of QThread and is used when you have many processes that will need a Thread from time to time to execute some code -- this is so that you do not have to create, throw-away and create Threads.   On the flip-side QThread should not be sub-classed.  Then as do all Threads in python you have to deal with the GIL which basically means only one process can run at a time so if you launch some continuous

Comment: process it may lock-up/freeze your GUI if you have not handled it properly.  Lastly as @eyllanesc sort-of pointed out anything using a QtWidget as well as some QtGui stuff -- one MUST put these within a Main Event Thread (QApplication) thus if you are wanting to separate the GUI from the processing you have to put them in separate Multiprocesses.